# Array with only even number

Tags: bash, sequence

`for X in {18..2500} ;` is one line of my script, which means to pick number one by one like: 18,19,20,21,22,23....till 2500

However I find I only need even number right now: 18,20,22,24.....2500

Then what should I do by a slight modify of the line?

Thanks

edit:
It's bash...

My script is now changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash



TASK=1101;

NUM=9;

TEND=1100;

for X in {18..2500};{

   if (X % 2 == 0);

   do

     echo "$X      echo \"Wait until $NUM job is done\" $NUM" ;

     NUM=$((NUM+2)) ;

     X=$((X+1)) ;

     TEND=$((TEND+100)) ;

     echo "$X      -t $TASK-$TEND jobs.sh" ;

     TASK=$((TASK+100)) ;}

done
```

but got errors like:
line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: could you give some more code example?  The snippet you gave could be used to do many different things.

Comment: The `for` statement isn't C but looks like it could be Python?

Comment: Looking at OP's questions it could be either Python or bash.

Comment: This is C++? Wow, that language seems to have changed a great deal since I used it.

Comment: this is not a valid code in python, and it's definitely not C++.

Comment: I fixed it a bit, it's not c++ and has nothing to do with arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not C++. This is a bash script.

Your `for`-loop needs to start with a `do`:

```
for X in {18..2500}; do
```

Your [`if`-statement syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) looks off. It should probably be something like this, note the `then`:

```
    if [[ $((X % 2)) == 0 ]]; then
```

`if`-blocks end with:

```
    fi
```

And the `for`-`do` block ends with:

```
done
```

Better still... do away with the `if` statement and use Bash's [`for`-loop construct](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) to generate only even numbers:

```
for ((X = 18; X <= 2500; X += 2)); do
     echo "$X      echo \"Wait until $NUM job is done\" $NUM" ;
     # ... 
done
```

Comment: Inside of `$(( ... ))` simple variables do not need a `$`: `$(( x % 2 ))`

Comment: @glenn: Thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly. I'm really no expert in Bash.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the increment:

```
for X in {18..2500..2}

   A sequence  expression takes the form {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are
   either integers or single characters, and incr, an optional increment, is
   an integer.
```

Or

```
for X in `seq 18 2 2500`
```

Comment: If this is indeed for bash, that doesn't work for me (just gives 19!).

Comment: huh? are you sure? `bash --version`?

Comment: Increment appears to require bash 4; doesn't work with stock Solaris 10 (3.00.16) or cygwin (3.2.51(24))

Comment: thx! that's a year old cygwin, after an update it should be fine  http://cygwin.com/packages/bash/

Answer (score 1):

Try the modulus operator. In almost all languages, it'll look something like this:

```
if (x % 2 == 0)    // …Do something
```

That is valid C code, but can easily be applied to other languages.

You can think of the mod operator as a division sign placed in the same location, but rather than returning the results of the division it returns the remainder. Therefore in this code, if the remainder of a divide-by-two is 0, then it divides evenly by two, and so it's even by definition.

Comment: The mod operator exists in both Python and bash.

Answer (score 1):

If your language has a `for(;;)`  syntax you can

```
for (X = 18; X <= 2500; X += 2)
```

Comment: In bash, this would be `for (( x=18; x<=2500; x+=2 )); do ...; done`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do:

1. use the modulus function for your language:

for x in {18..2500} {

if (x mod 2=0) {

do something;}

1. step through your For loop 2 at a time:

for x in {18..2500} step 2 {

do something;}